# CSS for Re-sizable menu height

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am having this website which has very long navigation menu. Please check below URL and the navigation menu 'Tech Group' -> 'Tech Meetings' and 'Business Group' -> 'Business Meeting'. These menu are so long that I am getting white space after the page. I want this menu to be auto resize as per the page size. I have tried css but getting no satisfying result.

http://prismeforum.org/new/top-content-for-prisme-members/meetings/2008-fall-daiichi-sankyo-usa/

check the above page for reference.

```
 {
   Position: fixed;
   height: auto;
   overflow-y: scroll;
 }
```

I have tried something like above css.

Comment: please add code and a jsfiddle... we can not help you with your problem without you code.

Answer (score 1):

add a class(like `menudiv`) to the sub menu which is floating outside and then add css

```
.menudiv {
overflow-y:scroll;
overflow-x:hidden;
height:50%;
}
```

and if you want to style the scroll then you can use

```
.menudiv::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 4px;
}

.menudiv::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
border-radius: 2px;
}

.menudiv::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
border-radius: 2px;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}
```